# Deriving Hamiltonian with Lagrange multiplier method

Tags: optimization, lagrange-multiplier, control-theory, economics, hamilton-jacobi-equation

This is probably a basic concept, but I am having a hard time understanding why in deriving the Hamiltonian with the Lagrange multiplier method 1) we introduce a time-varying multiplier for optimization and 2) we take derivatives with respect to functions as if they were constants.

I've looked through a few chapters in some optimal control textbooks and convex optimization, and am still a bit confused.

During class, my professor showed us this proof:

$$
\begin{gathered}
\max _{\{c(t)\}_{t \geq 0}} \int_0^{\infty} u(c(t)) e^{-\rho t} dt \text {, s.t., } \\
\dot{k}(t)=f(k(t))-c(t), \text { for all } t \geq 0 .
\end{gathered}
$$

Where $k(t)$ is our state variable, $u, f$ are continuous, strictly concave functions, and $\rho$ is a positive constant.

My professor first starts with a Lagrangian and uses some algebra:
$$
\mathcal{L}=  \int_0^{\infty} u(c(t)) e^{-\rho t} d t+\int_0^{\infty} \mu(t)[f(k(t))-c(t)-\dot{k}(t)] d t 
$$
$$
\mathcal{L}=  \int_0^{\infty} u(c(t)) e^{-\rho t}+\mu(t)[f(k(t))-c(t)] d t-\int_0^{\infty} \mu(t) \dot{k}(t) d t
$$
Integration by parts:
$$
\int_0^{\infty} \mu(t) \dot{k}(t) d t=\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \mu(t) k(t)-\mu(0) k_0-\int_0^{\infty} \dot{\mu}(t) k(t) d t .
$$
Define the function
$$
\mathcal{H} \equiv u(c(t)) e^{-\rho t}+\mu(t)[f(k(t))-c(t)],
$$
so that we have
$$
\mathcal{L}=\mu(0) k_0-\lim _{t \rightarrow \infty} \mu(t) k(t)+\int_0^{\infty}[\mathcal{H}+\dot{\mu}(t) k(t)] d t
$$

Then,  he says that the first-order condition for consumption is
$$
u^{\prime}(c(t)) e^{-\rho t}=\mu(t) \text {, for all } t \geq 0 .
$$

But, I'm still quite confused about

1. Why is it necessary for the multiplier $\mu(t)$ to be time-varying? In the discrete-time case, we still were able to solve the problem with only 1 multiplier. Since it's possible to derive the integral by using an infinite sum, wouldn't a single multiplier suffice in this case too?
2. When, in general, can we treat a function as a constant and take derivatives with respect to that function? In this above first order condition, we obtained it by taking the derivative of the integrand with respect to $c(t)$. But, in doing so, it seems we took $c(t)$ as a constant. Does this require any assumptions about the function $\mathcal{H} - \dot{\mu}(t)k(t)$?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The discrete version seems identical to page 12 here http://www.econ.yale.edu/smith/rochester/chapter3.pdf which has a time varying multiplier, one for each constraint.

Comment: Do you understand why this is the case?

Comment: In other problems, it appears that we are permitted to take the multiplier outside of the sum and use a constant multiplier

Comment: "In the discrete-time case, we still were able to solve the problem with only 1 multiplier." Could it be that you're confusing the discrete-time case with the static case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. Why is it necessary for the multiplier $\mu(t)$ to be time-varying?
>    In the discrete-time case, we still were able to solve the problem
>    with only 1 multiplier. Since it's possible to derive the integral by
>    using an infinite sum, wouldn't a single multiplier suffice in this
>    case too?

1. We have to have as many multipliers as we have constraints. Thus, since the constraint applies for each infinitesimal time t, we have to have the multiplier be time-varying.

> 2. When, in general, can we treat a function as a constant and take
>    derivatives with respect to that function? In this above first order
>    condition, we obtained it by taking the derivative of the integrand
>    with respect to $c(t)$. But, in doing so, it seems we took $c(t)$ as a
>    constant. Does this require any assumptions about the function
>    $\mathcal{H} - \dot{\mu}(t)k(t)$?

2. Here, we are not taking the derivative with respect to the function, $c(t)$. Rather, we're taking the derivative with respect to $c$ at a particular time $t$. The idea is that at all arbitrary times $t$, we must have the first order condition for this Lagrange multiplier hold. Thus, we can take the derivative with respect to consumption $c$ at an arbitrary time $t$.